# Generate chart using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have made code to generate chart using javascript and it works fine, as you can see in snipped code that data is hardcoded, the problem is how to make this code work with ajax data instead of hardcoded data?

Code:

```
   window.onload = function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
            {
                title: {
                    text: "Average monthly rainfull for 30 years"
                },
                animationEnabled: true,
                axisY: {
                    title: "Precipitation inches",
                    includeZero: false
                },
                axisX: {
                    title: "Months",
                    interval: 1
                },
                toolTip: {
                    shared: true,
                    content: function (e) {
                        var body = new String;
                        var head;
                        for (var i = 0; i < e.entries.length; i++) {
                            var str = "<span style = 'color:"+e.entries[i].dataSeries.color + "'> " + e.entries[i].dataSeries.name + "</span>: strong" + e.entries[i].dataPoint.y+ "</strong>''<br/>";

                            body = body.concat(str);
                        }
                        head = "<span style = color:DodgerBlue;'><strong>" + (e.entries[0].dataPoint.label) + "</strong></span><br/>";
                        return (head.concat(body));
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    horizontalAlign: "center",
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        type: "spline",
                        showInLegend: true,
                        name: "Boston",
                        dataPoints: [

                            { label: "Jan", y: 3.1 },
                            { label: "Feb", y: 3.32 },
                            { label: "Mar", y: 3.2 },
                            { label: "Apr", y: 3.4 },
                            { label: "May", y: 3.5 },
                            { label: "Jun", y: 3.6 },
                            { label: "Jul", y: 3.7},
                            { label: "Aug", y: 3.8 },
                            { label: "Sep", y: 3.9 },
                            { label: "Oct", y: 3.10 },
                            { label: "Nov", y: 3.11},
                            { label: "Dec", y: 3.12}


                        ]
                    },
                {
                type: "spline",
                showInLegend: true,
                name: "Yemen",
                dataPoints: [

                    { label: "Jan", y: 4.1 },
                    { label: "Feb", y: 5.32 },
                    { label: "Mar", y: 2.2 },
                    { label: "Apr", y: 4.4 },
                    { label: "May", y: 1.5 },
                    { label: "Jun", y: 4.6 },
                    { label: "Jul", y: 9.7},
                    { label: "Aug", y: 4.8 },
                    { label: "Sep", y: 3.9 },
                    { label: "Oct", y: 2.10 },
                    { label: "Nov", y: 5.11},
                    { label: "Dec", y: 3.12}
                ]
            }
                ],
                legend: {
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    itemClick: function (e) {
                        if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                            e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                        } else {
                            e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                        }
                        chart.render();
                    }
                }
            });
        chart.render();
    }
```

ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var url_list = "api/usergroup/getdata";
        $.getJSON(url_list)
        .done(function (data) {

        });
    });
```

Data look like :

```
[{"id":1,"state_code":"JHR","state_name":"Jor","category_code":"DAM","station_code":"BEKOK-P","station_name"
:"Bekok Dam Penstock","item_id":1,"desc":"Test Expenses","qty":2,"price":19.00,"total":38.00,"date":"2016-01-05T17
:26:10","remark":"1. just for test purpose."}]
```

Comment: What is the format of the data returned from `api/usergroup/getdata`?

Comment: the format of data is JSON

Comment: Have you tried simply placing _"your"_ code inside the `done` callback in your example and use the `data` parameter instead of the hardcoded data? If not, that could be a good place to start.

Comment: Simply create a function that take the json response as a parameter and call it inside the ajax callback

Comment: will try that. it seems good idea,

Comment: a quick search gives [this](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/)

Comment: @Smart well, yes, but what is the format of the JSON? What properties does it have? Does it match the existing data structure you're providing to the chart plugin?

Comment: I have updated question, please look at it .

Answer (score 0):

http://www.highcharts.com/

This is a javascript api for chart creation

Comment: How does this answer the question?